# i cannot run the file.. it keep error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P3Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [] score = new int [20];
        int i=0;
        System.out.print("Enter the scores(negative number to end)\n");

        do{
            System.out.printf("\nscore[%d]:", i+1);              
             int y = scan.nextInt();
            score[i]=y;

            ++i;
        }while( y = 0);


    }
}
```

it keeps display error when run the project. can somenoe help me? i am a java beginner

Comment: Please put some effort into your questions. Read the Help Center on how to ask a question.

Comment: "it keeps display error" ==> that's so great! But what's the error???

Comment: In addition to the full exception (e.g. nullPointerException) the stack trace would be useful (usually outputted directly after the exception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use `while( y = 0);` since `y` is not defined outside of the loop.
`y` is declared only in the loop. So the loop can check a condition on a variable on which it does not have visibility.

You have to declare y outside of the loop:

```
 int y;
 do{
     System.out.printf("\nscore[%d]:", i+1);              
     y = scan.nextInt();
     score[i]=y;

     ++i;
 }while( y == 0);
```

**Edit:**

As Richard Tingle said in a comment (deleted now), your while condition seems not to be good. You have to put `while (y == 0)` and not `while (y = 0)` if you want to check `y` equality to 0. In your case, you just set a value to `y`.